# Cannot properly parse json string to JavaScript object

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to parse a json string I get back from localStorage back to a JavaScript object, but it does not work. The json string I get back looks like this:

```
[{"baseLayer":"Swiss Chard","condiment":"Vindaloo Sauce","mixing":"Veggies for Fish Tacos","seasoning":"Sriracha Marinade","shell":"Perfect Flour Tortillas"},{"baseLayer":"Pork Shoulder with Chile and Onions","condiment":"Salsa Sauce","mixing":"Veggies for Fish Tacos","seasoning":"Sriracha Marinade","shell":"Low Carb Tacos"}]
```

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { NavContext } from '../contexts/NavContext';

const Favorites = () => {
let { toggleNav } = useContext(NavContext);
let [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(localStorage.getItem('combinationsArray'));

/*setFavorites(JSON.parse(favorites)); logs Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't 
have access to the actual error object in development.*/

/*favorites = JSON.parse(favorites); logs Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object 
with keys {baseLayer, condiment, mixing, seasoning, shell}). If you meant to render a collection of 
children, use an array instead.*/

favorites = Array.isArray((JSON.parse(favorites)) && JSON.parse(favorites)); // works, but just 
returns true

console.log(JSON.parse(favorites)); // logs the correct JavaScript array, but I cannot use it 
outside of console.log

return (
    <div className="favorites" >
        <img className="menu" src={require("../img/tacomenu.png")} onClick={toggleNav} />
        <div className="favorites-title">YOUR FAVORITES</div>
        <div>{ favorites }</div>
    </div>
);
}

export default Favorites;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just problem with brackets

```js
let favorites  = '[{"baseLayer":"Swiss Chard","condiment":"Vindaloo Sauce","mixing":"Veggies for Fish Tacos","seasoning":"Sriracha Marinade","shell":"Perfect Flour Tortillas"},{"baseLayer":"Pork Shoulder with Chile and Onions","condiment":"Salsa Sauce","mixing":"Veggies for Fish Tacos","seasoning":"Sriracha Marinade","shell":"Low Carb Tacos"}]';
favorites = Array.isArray(JSON.parse(favorites)) && JSON.parse(favorites); // <--- right 
console.log(favorites);
```